# Switch case expression

Tags: c, switch-statement

Consider an expression `*(1+"AB" "CD"+1)`

What is the solution for this expression ? The above expression is a switch expression in C.

```
*(2+"AB" "CD") --> *(2+"ABCD") --> ?
```

After this what should I do?
Below is the code snippet:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
     switch(*(1+"AB" "CD"+1)){
        case 'A':printf("Pulp Fiction");
                  break;
        case 'B':printf("12 Angry Man");
                  break;
        case 'C':printf("Casabance");
                  break;
        case 'D':printf("Blood Diamond");
     }

}
```

Comment: did you try running it? What was the output?

Comment: Why are you writing unreadable code?

Comment: If this is homework, use chosen language with your professor about the lack of style: incorrect prototype for `main()` and error prone missing `break;` at the end of the switch block.

Answer (score 6):

Casabance.

If you have

```
char *cp;
int i;
```

then `cp[i] == *(cp+i) == *(i+cp) == i[cp]`.

C11 6.5.2.1:

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
>   is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
>   definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to
>   (*((E1)+(E2))).

And C11 6.5.6:

> When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted
>   from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the
>   pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array
>   is large enough, the result points to an element offset from the
>   original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the
>   resulting and original array elements equals the integer expression.

A string literal is just a char pointer as far as the compiler is concerned.

Two string literals  next to each other auto concatenate into a single string literal:

C11 6.4.5:

> In translation phase 6, the multibyte character sequences specified by
>   any sequence of adjacent character and identically-prefixed string
>   literal tokens are concatenated into a single multibyte character
>   sequence.

So... `*(1+"AB" "CD"+1) == *(1+"ABCD"+1) == *("ABCD"+1+1)==*("BCD"+1) == "BCD"[1] == 'C'`.

Comment: Your last line has some errors, there is a `+` too much for the first expression, and toward the end there must be `2`s instead of `1`s.

Comment: I fixed the string cat, thanks. The ones at the end were on purpose. Addition is left to right so `"ABCD"+1+1 == "BCD"+1` not `"ABCD"+2`. I really should have put  `1+"ABCD"+1 == "BCD"+1` as one step, but decided not to for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

Running your code you'll get answer "Casabance"

- `"AB" "CD"` is equal to `"ABCD"`
- `*("ABCD")` points to `'A'`
- `*("ABCD" + 0)` points to `'A'`
- `*("ABCD" + 1)` points to `'B'`
- `*("ABCD" + 2)` points to `'C'`
- `'C'` answer is "Casabance"

Answer (score 1):

Here is a description of the different steps, all performed at compile time:

- The sequence of string literals `"AB" "CD"` is concatenated at compile time into a single string literal `"ABCD"`.
- This string literal compiles to an array of 5 `char`, initialized with the values `'A'`, `'B'`, `'C'`, `'D'` and `'\0'`.
- In the expression `1 + "ABCD" + 1`, the array decays into a pointer to its first element, said pointer is incremented by 2 to point to the third element, in this case the `C` byte.
- Dereferencing this pointer evaluates to the `char` value `'C'`.
- The switch expression has a constant value `'C'`, converted to an `int`, although it is not a *constant expression* as defined by the C Standard.
- The compiler will likely optimize the `switch` into a single call to `printf` with the string `"Casabance"`, as can be verified on http://gcc.godbolt.org/#

Note that the prototype for `main` in incorrect in your example, it should be `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` or equivalent.  Furthermore, it is error prone to omit the `break;` at the end of the last `case` or `default` clause in the `switch` block.

Comment: *The switch expression is therefore constant* The expression in the switch is not constant.

Comment: @2501: The expression in the `switch` need not be constant. It can be treated by the compiler in this case as such.

Comment: @2501: Good point, I shall rephrase my explanation, the expression has a constant value although it is not a *constant expression* as defined by the C Standard.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanations.It really helped me and gave clarity. :)

Comment: @user2870464: can you accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score?